# Creating Cognito users from frontend application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm currently getting started with aws services. I'm trying to build an admin UI for managing a cognito user pool. E.g I want to have some cognito users to have admin rights for creating new users from the UI etc. I'm a bit confused by the docs on the different ways to integrate authentication in API gateway, Lambda and DynamoDB. Do I need a Identity Pool for that use case? Or just different User Pool roles?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: what do you mean by different user pool roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use AWS resources you do need identity pool. You should create user [groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html) in your user pool and assign them different [roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html#assigning-iam-roles-to-groups) in IAM. After this, create an identity pool and select cognito identity under the authentication providers. Also make sure you select "Choose Role from token".